# static mutex and multithreading

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

If I declare a mutex as static in a function and use that mutex to lock a certain variable. Is that mutex 'shared' between threads, e.g I can get away with using a little bit of cleaner code?

example of appending a string to a double pointer char type, I want to call something like this from multiple threads:

```
void func(char *msg) {
    static pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    static char **buffer;
    static unsigned int i=0;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    buffer = realloc(++i * sizeof(char *));
    buffer[i-1] = realloc(strlen(msg) + 1);
    strcpy(buffer[i-1], msg);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

    return;

}
```

Comment: Why would you use mutexes to protect your resources then totally disregard the possibility that the lock may return with failure :-)

Comment: because it`s an example. of course I can totally write 4 times the code and errcheck everything correctly. But that was not the point of this question. Also you forget realloc can also fail :)

Comment: your second `realloc` is wrong. `sizeof(msg)` is the size of the pointer, not of the message. I suppose it should be `buffer[i-1] = malloc(strlen(msg)+1);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a statically initialized mutex is shared between threads - otherwise it would not be very useful. `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` is designed exactly for use cases like yours.

Note that you need to increment `i` after locking the mutex. As written before the edit, the code contained a data race (itself undefined behavior) and was open to a race condition if multiple threads executed it in parallel.